# Constructing DataFrame for mean and median data

Tags: python, pandas

I am completely new to DataFrames and Pandas. I have data which looks like this :

> {"_kaats": {"median": 15.783333333333333, "mean": 613.08480293921173},
>   "ryanleslie": {"median": 3921.4666666666667, "mean":
>   7279.5321839080461}}

I am trying to convert it into DataFrame so that the mean and median is the row and name is the column.

My current attempt looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(result_dict)
print df
```

But it produces different output. Can someone hlpe me out here.

Comment: What output do you get and what output do you want?

Comment: pd.DataFrame({"_kaats": {"median": 15.783333333333333, "mean": 613.08480293921173}, "ryanleslie": {"median": 3921.4666666666667, "mean": 7279.5321839080461}}) should give you what you want, please share what you are actually getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for pandas DataFrame from dictionary...

```
dict_data = {"_kaats": {"median": 15.783333333333333, "mean": 613.08480293921173}, "ryanleslie": {"median": 3921.4666666666667, "mean": 7279.5321839080461}}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_data, orient='index')
print(df)
```

orient index output:

```
                 median         mean
_kaats        15.783333   613.084803
ryanleslie  3921.466667  7279.532184
```

orient columns output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_data)
print(df)

           _kaats   ryanleslie
mean    613.084803  7279.532184
median   15.783333  3921.466667
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what  I was after.